# What's the standard file extension for textile files?

Tags: markdown, file-extension, textile

What's the standard file extension for textile files? I know that `.md` is commonly used for markdown files. I didn't know if there was a standard for textile.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to the [Vim plugin that tells Vim how to handle Textile files](https://github.com/jtimberman/dotvim/blob/master/plugin/textile.vim), it's `.textile`.